# Как убрать файл, который уже есть в .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Как убрать workspace.xml, чтобы он не индексировался?

В `.gitignore` написано

```
.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
.idea
/.idea
*/.idea/workspace.xml
```

но она все равно индексируется.

Comment: git rm -r --cached .idea

Comment: @etki сделал так, первый коммит будто удалил эти файлы, а следующий коммит не добавляет и как будто изменяет эти файлы, их там 13, то есть опять индексируются

Comment: @eldqs, будто? Где валяется гитигнор?

Comment: в папке проекта в корне, получается сначала он удалил было написано удалено 13 файлов а при втором коммите он заново индексирует и написано изменено 13 файлов, то есть файлы которые удалил.

Comment: @eldqs, это проблемы гитигнора, судя по всему. Не знаю, почему он его игнорирует, но в первый раз, судя по всему, всё прошло ок. С помощью git status можно посмотреть, что гит хочет сделать с файлами при следующем коммите, там же будет видно, когда гитигнор начнет действовать.

Comment: Решение в общем виде: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432895/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**наболее краткий вариант** (всего *две* изменяющие что-либо команды)

1. рекурсивно удаляем из репозитория каталог (рабочая копия не затрагивается — меняется только содержимое индекса):

   ```
   $ git rm -r --cached .idea
   ```

   перед `git commit` всегда полезно посмотреть `git status` и убедиться, что всё идёт так, как надо:

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch master
   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

       deleted:    .idea/workspace.xml
   ```
2. всё в порядке. делаем `commit`. рабочая копия тем более не затрагивается — меняется содержимое репозитория (всего того, что находится в каталоге `.git`):

   ```
   $ git commit ...
   ```

проверяем:

```
$ ls .idea
workspace.xml
```

да, файл на месте.

а в `.gitignore` достаточно оставить одну строку (из всех озвученных в вопросе):

```
.idea
```

Comment: $ не является внутренней или внешней коммандой.. куда это "$ git rm -r --cached .idea" вводить?

Comment: @SergeyShturnev, знак доллара в данном случае означает приглашение оболочки. сама команда — это то, что после знака доллара.

Answer (score 6):

Видимо, файлам уже был ранее сделан commit,
поможет

```
mv .idea .idea1
git rm -r .idea
git commit [--amend]
mv .idea1 .idea
```

Либо правка ранее сделанных коммитов `git rebase -i ...` и там `git rm -r --cached .idea`

Comment: А чтобы не делать дважды `mv`, можно один раз добавить `--cached`.

Comment: Я думал --cached только к изменениям подготовленным для коммита относится, а нет, в зависимости от того с чем совпадает содержимое - либо из индекса либо из ветки.