# Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore

Tags: git, git-reset, gitignore, git-rm

Читаю книгу Test-Driven Development with Python, во второй главе описывается создание git-репозитория. Я следую всем инструкциям, но мой файл `.gitignore` не игнорирует записанное в нём. В чём проблема?

[image: pic]

Comment: Вероятно вы добавили в .gitignore файлы, которые уже попали в ваш репозиторий 
попробуйте git rm --cached, как там написано

Comment: @Darth, оформите, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: А покажите содержимое файла .gitignore, а то есть подозрение, что там db.sqlite3 может быть записан не на отдельной строке, а где-то после другой сигнатуры.

Судя по скриншоту, не похоже, что файлы уже попали в репозиторий, поскольку git status отмечает их как новые.

Comment: Присоединюсь к догадке @Darth

Comment: Дмитрий, как там ваш репозиторий? Получилось решить задачу?

Comment: Да, удалил всё и по новой создал. Со второй попытки все хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Подозреваю, что вы добавили файлы в индекс раньше, чем начали игнорировать. То есть до той `git add .`, который на скриншоте, была еще одна такая команда. Чтобы узнать точно, не хватает `git status` перед добавлением.

Если файл уже был добавлен, то изменение в `.gitignore` не вызывает удаления из текущего индекса (что логично и безопасно).

#### Если файлы только добавлены, но еще не включены в коммит

В данном конкретном случае именно так и есть. При этом достаточно удалить их из индекса. Данная команда возвращает индекс к HEAD, то есть состоянию последнего коммита.

```
git reset <file-name>
```

Вы можете заметить, что сам Git предлагает использовать другую команду:

```
git rm --cached <file-name>
```

*В данном случае* эти команды эквивалентны. Такое дублирование появилось в результате эволюционного развития функционала Git. Это в том числе отражено в документации и в сообщениях Git: где-то рекомендуется `reset`, где-то `rm --cached`.

#### Если игнорируемые файлы уже есть в последнем коммите

Возможна и такая ситуация, на всякий случай я опишу и ее. Здесь `reset` не сработает, нужен `rm`. Аргумент `--cached` заставляет Git удалить файл из индекса, но не трогать рабочую область. То есть он буквально индексирует удаление файла, хотя этого удаления не было. Если сделать это с файлом, который не игнорируется, то после коммита он будет в категории неотслеживаемых (untracked).

```
git rm --cached <file-name>
```

Если нужно убрать целую игнорируемую папку, добавляем ключ -r:

```
git rm -r --cached <path>
```

Эта [удобная команда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797830/2790048) применяет `rm` ко всем файлам, указанным в `.gitignore`:

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`
```

Вариант того же [для windows powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore#comment22340509_14797830):

```
foreach ($i in iex 'git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore') { git rm --cached $i }
```

Теперь результат команды `git rm` нужно зафиксировать коммитом.

```
git commit -m'removed gitignored files'
```

Answer (score 14):

Команда

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`
```

имеет проблемы с пробелами в названиях.

Самый простой путь - удалить из кэша ВСЕ файлы, и добавить заново с учетом gitignore. на все про все 2 команды.

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git add .
```

потом закоммитить:

```
git commit -m "fix gitignore"
```

Comment: Что за проблемы с пробелами команды которая в начале вашей записи?

Answer (score 0):

```
git filter-branch --force (чтобы не удалился каталог с жесткого диска)

git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf PATH" HEAD
```

где PATH - путь к файлу/папке

https://toster.ru/q/176843

https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Answer (score 0):

На ваш вопрос ответ простой. Наименование файлов и директорий которые игнорируются гитом должны быть записаны в .gitignore без кавычек ("). Пример в книге добавляет в .gitignore имена файлов обрамленные кавычками, в результате гит не может их идентифицировать. У берите кавычки и все будет работать.