# Уйдут ли на gitHub игнорируемые файлы при коммите, если они отмечены в диалоге commit в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, gitignore

**Дано:**

1. Файл с паролями, коий не надо заливать на GitHub.
2. В `.gitignore` этот файл прописан и в студии помечен серым цветом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:**

При коммите сей файл отмечен и выделен в списке файлов для коммита:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**

Что таки произойдёт при коммит->пуш? Файл сохранится на GitHub и будет всем доступен или просто в истории коммитов будет значится как добавленный в проект но существовать физически будет только на моей машине из-за добавления в gitignore?

**P.S.**
т.к. в файле пароли и явки пробовать сам  опасаюсь(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: @YuraIvanov, а через студию никак?.. А то я с командной строкой не дружу - непонятно как ей сказать, что я хочу `git` команды в определённой папке выполнить(

Comment: боюсь, что это слишком редкий кейс, чтоб он был в студии. Я по крайней мере такого функционала у себя не нашел...

Comment: @YuraIvanov, получилось всё после удаления файла из студийного проекта, коммита и его последующего добавления. Теперь всё верно игнориуется. Неожиданное поведение(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб про команды в определенной папке- посмотрите мой вопрос про git add, там есть ответ

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а ссылочку?..

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ОК, спс) Найду - сам добавлю)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431839/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мы одновременно нашли)

Comment: Вот на основной вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432895/181472

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему удалив файл из проекта, сделав коммит без него и добавив его снова.
После этих манипуляций файл перестал появляться в списке файлов для коммита.

Видимо надо сначала составлять `.gitignore` а потом уже только добавлять в проект игнорируемые файлы.

---

Согласно [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/3212712) @Yura Ivanov, для тех, кто умеет в командную строку достаточно выполнить такую команду для игнорирования файлов, добавленных до изменения `.gitignore`:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Comment: Но ведь в ссылке на en SO предложили вариант сделать тоже самое через команду `git rm --cached <file>`, чтобы не отслеживались файлы, которые были добавлены (`add`) еще до составления `gitignore`.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, к сожалению я не дружу с командной строй. Я честно попытался через стандартную вызвать `git` команды в папке с моим проектом и через `gitshell` перейти в неё же. В первом случае команды такой не опознала командная строка, во втором я не смог примеры из гугла применить. Чтобы пользоваться командной строкой надо уметь ей пользоваться(

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, и, кстати, спасибо - на решение вы меня натолкнули своим удалённым комментом)

Comment: Судя по всему, вы быстро прочитали его :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, я как бешеный жал на `F5` сразу после публикации) Уж очень меня сия проблема раздражала  - вчера пришлось идти спать так её и не решив(