# Как удалить каталог из списка контроля версий?

Tags: git, pycharm

Как удалить каталог, случайно добавленный в список контроля версий? В PyCharm при создании новых объектов (файлов, каталогов), система предлагает включить его в список контролируемых файлов:

[image: Add file to git]

Кроме того, файл можно добавить в git вручную:

[image: Add file manually]

Как удалить файл из системы контроля версий? Не помогает даже добавление файла/каталога в список игнорируемых файлов:

[image: Список игнорируемых файлов]

Хотя игнорируемый файл должен быть написано красным шрифтом, как видите, это не так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** после совета от @Etki

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А пытаюсь я сделать нечто вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: гит игнорирует пустые папки и не ведет трекинг папок как таковых, только файлов

Comment: @Etki я не очень хорошо владею git'ом, поэтому поясню как я это вижу. Раньше каталог был помечен красным шрифтом и не коммитился по-умолчанию (иначе говоря - игнорировался). Я по ошибке добавил его в список контроля версий, и теперь при каждом коммите система предлагает мне закоммитить 2500 файлов виртуальной среды.

Comment: не оно? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo

Comment: @NikolaTesla как открыть консольку git'a в pycharm?

Comment: правой кнопкой - mark directory as - ignored. возможно, придется еще повозиться в консоли с гитом

Comment: @jumpjet67 а в системной консоли у Вас гит не доступен?

Comment: еще возможно прокатит, если сделать копию файла, оригинальный фал удалить, сделать коммит, а потом восстановить копию из файла.

Comment: Совет @Etki сработал, но по-прежнему не понятно, почему значёк помечер красным, не название, а файлы внутри по-прежнему помечены как "к коммиту" (см. обновление выше)

Comment: игнорирование и удаление также надо зафиксировать (commit)

Comment: @NikolaTesla не помогло, сделать нужно как в UPD2 (см. выше)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уже проиндексировали (добавили, add) какой-то файл или папку, git просто так о них не забудет, даже если добавить их в `.gitignore`. Нужно немного помочь git через консоль (в интерфейсе я не нашёл такой возможности). У меня консоль открывается по Alt + F12.

```
git reset flaskenv
```

Теперь эта папка исключена из индекса и попадёт туда снова, только если добавите. В сочетании с `.gitignore` работает отлично.

Подробнее: [Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432432/181472)