# Игнорирование конфигурационного файла в git

Tags: git, gitignore

Есть файл конфигурации БД. Он должен хранится в репо с другими значениями, а в локалке с другими. Создал файл bd.js, добавил настройки и сделал push. После этого меняю этот файл на локалке и хочу заигнорить, но не получается. Пробовал с помощью info/exclude, .gitignore, .gitconfig.

Файлы которых нет в репо игнорятся, но bd.js нет. Посоветуете?

Comment: .gitignore предотвращает добавление новых файлов в индекс по умолчанию, но с теми, которые уже там, он ничего не делает. Вам нужно удалить файл из индекса.

Comment: Если не сложно дополните вопрос строкой из .gitignore, правило в этом файле добавлено уже после того, как файл запушен или до?

Comment: [Дубликат вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432432/), частый вопрос, в FAQ можно заносить. Вкратце: вам вообще не нужно хранить файл конфигурации в git'е, можно хранить пример файла конфигурации, настоящие пароли -- не нужно. Тем более, что у вас две разных конфигурации.

Comment: `.gitignore:   utils/mysqlConnData.js`
Правило добавил после push-а, так как надо было в репо отправить конфиг, а потом поменять локальные настройки

Comment: Файл конфигурации приходится хранить в гите, так как хостинг работает через него. Я про openshift.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4744071/4827341

Comment: *Я про openshift* — в подобных случаях, вероятно, имеет смысл передавать необходимые параметры через переменные окружения. если их слишком много, можно передавать лишь имя (или путь к) файла с конфигурацией. а ваша программа должна этими переменными окружения воспользоваться. а если они не установлены, использовать умолчания.