# Правильное добавление .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-bash

Работал над проектом. В один момент перестал работать .gitignore (лишние файлы в репозиторий запушились). Удалил,создал новый. Как правильно его залить на репозиторий, с другими файлами или без? Потому что я уже попробовал кучу способов и все равно лишние файлы остаются. Сам файл .gitignore взял у знакомого, у него все работает (такая же ОС, вижуалка и тоже плюсы).

Comment: *лишние файлы в репозиторий запушились* — так не бывает. коммиты (не файлы, конечно), сами собой не «запушиваются». а в коммит попадают ровно те *изменения в файлах*, которые вы в него (коммит) внесли **сами**.

Comment: если вы делаете коммит «не глядя», да ещё и с опцией `-a` — это, пмсм, плохая практика.

Comment: фактически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432432/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin делают коммит с опцией -m. Я предполагал, что при добавление файла ,gitignore в папку с проектом при пуше в репозиторий они не запушатся (которые указаны в .gitignore).

Answer (score 2):

если файл **уже** отслеживается в текущей ветке, то добавление/удаление его имени (или шаблона, под который подпадает его имя) в/из файла `.gitignore` **никак не повлияет** на поведение команды `git commit -a`:

те изменения, которые вы внесли в этот **отслеживаемый** файл, будут добавлены в индекс и затем в коммит.

чтобы программа *git* перестала отслеживать изменения в файле, этот файл надо удалить из хранилища:

```
$ git rm путь/к/файлу
```

и закоммитить это изменение.

---

> Как правильно его залить на репозиторий, с другими файлами или без?

собственно, файл `.gitignore` можно даже и не «заливать» в удалённое хранилище. «заливается» он исключительно для удобства *других* пользователей хранилища: чтобы у всех были идентичные настройки игнорируемых файлов/каталогов.

содержимое же файла `.gitignore` имеет «непосредственное» действие. пример:

1. создаём файл:

   ```
   $ touch file
   ```
2. этот файл отображается в выводе команды `git status` как неотслеживаемый:

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch master
   Untracked files:
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

       file

   nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
   ```
3. если мы добавим его имя в файл `.gitignore`:

   ```
   $ echo file >> .gitignore
   ```
4. то команда `git status` уже не будет отображать это файл как неотслеживаемый (т.е., программа *git* будет **игнорировать** любые изменения в этом файле):

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch master
   Untracked files:
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

       .gitignore

   nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
   ```

---

p.s. по поводу «можно даже и не „заливать“»: чтобы в такой ситуации файл `.gitignore` не «мозолил глаза» в выводе `git status` как неотслеживаемый (с предложением добавить его в хранилище), можно имя самого этого файла добавить в его содержимое:

```
$ echo .gitignore >> .gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

например у вас есть в директории файлы *.log. 
Команда git status показывает их. Как только вы добавите в .gitignore строчку *.log, то команда git status не будет показывать их. Проверьте что файл .gitignore у вас в папке где лежит папка .git

Comment: Если лишние файлы уже закоммичены ("запушены"), как у автора вопроса, то добавление их в gitignore никак не поможет.

Comment: он же удалил и создал новый

Comment: Ага, удалил gitignore и создал новый. Сами лишние файлы в системе контроля версий так и остались.

Comment: Я думаю, что он удалил репозиторий и создал новый

Comment: @inzem77 репозиторий остался. Если файлы закомичены, запушены на удаленный репозиторий я разве не могу добавить .gitignor так, чтобы файлы игнорировались на репозитории?

Comment: Добавь их в .gitignore и удали из репозитория git rm mylogfile.log

Answer (score -1):

проверьте на наличие файла .npmignore в проекте, если он есть - то gitignore не будет работать
https://medium.com/@echobrain/11-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-npm-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82-d00510587ec

Comment: Это неправда, npm-файлы абсолютно никак не влияют на git-репозиторий.