# Не всё исключает gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

В gitignore указаны исключения для файлов

```
*.xml
*.csv
```

однако при git st они выводятся

```
modified:   sitemap.xml
modified:   sitemap_iblock_2.part7.xml
modified:   test/tmp.csv
```

Что может быть не так?

Comment: а ты до этого их комиттил?

Comment: Наверняка дело в этом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432432/181472

Comment: да, 100 раз, просто времени не было разбираться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем как я вижу это. Был коммит, где все это было добавлено. Далее вы решили, что эти файлы не нужны, добавив .gitignore. Ну он и не добавляет новые файлы, которые вам не нужны, а те, что уже добавлены, так и остаются добавленными.

Comment: Возможно. А как сделать, чтобы они больше не появлялись? Если удалять руками, то их может быть очень много.

Comment: либо git rm --cached <file-name> либо по тупому - берешь все файлы, которые хочешь игнорить, вырезаешь в другую папку, делаешь коммит с удаленными файлами, снова заносишь их обратно и вуаля)) все работает