# Проблема с commit на Github

Tags: git, gitignore

на данный момент программирую вместе с товарищем , оба начинающие в работе с git . каким образом сделать так , чтобы при каждом коммите не появлялись данные изменения ? Оба используем IDE PyCharm .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в `.gitignore` ненужные файлы. В стандартном `.gitignore` из плагина PyCharm `.pyc` там уже добавлены

Comment: @dIm0n после добавления в gitignore , они всё ещё появляются

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432432/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать файл .gitignore (именно так, с точно в самом начале) и добавить туда

```
backenv/
```

Это будет игнорировать содержимое папки backenv.