# Через какую команду можно сделать так, чтобы git не отслеживал папку sass?

Tags: git

пишу git add src и git отслеживает всю папку, включая папку sass. Как сделать, так, чтобы папка sass игнорировалась? Может есть возможность прописать ее в gitignore? Читал, что этот файл нужен для игнорирование ненужных папок для git. Пытался прописать там папку sass, но ничего не вышло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Cначала добавить в `.gitignore` потом делать `git add`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432432/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-gitignore)

Comment: Из вопроса понятно только, что что-то там пытался. Что именно - неизвестно.

Comment: Задам лучше вопрос по другому. Как добавить папку в gitignore? Чтобы git не записывал его?

Answer (score 2):

В общем решил проблему. Добавил в gitignore путь к папке, сохранил. Потом в терминале прописал команду команду git rm -r --cached <пусть к папке>
"Пример: git rm -r -cached src/sass". Теперь пишем git add src/. После git status, и видим, что есть все папки и файлы, которые есть в src кроме папки sass.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]