# Как удалить каталог из синхронизации Git?

Tags: git

Git зацепил каталог venv. Как его убрать?
Варианты в gitignore:

```
/venv/
venv/
venv/*.*
venv/*
```

На том же уровне, что и venv лежат другие файлы и каталоги. Правила по ним работают нормально:

```
__pycache__/
*.pyc
*.sqlite3
```

Но venv никак уходить не хочет.
[image: Вкладка git в MVSC]

Структура файлов в git-проекте:

[image: Структура файлов]

Comment: если вы его уже зафиксировали - то только удалять, на отслеживаемые объекты игнор не распространяется

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432432/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-gitignore)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте этот вариант, по крайней мере так я экранирую каталог со скриптами (js):

```
*.venv_
```